# Setting up elb with aws with ssl cert

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb

I have ELB setup in AWS

```
1. TCP port 443 forward to 8080 port on instance (nginx)
2. www.example.com point to ELB dns
3. myserver.mydomain is my instance hostname
```

Now i have setup ssl on ELB for domain `www.example.com`

Now for ssl on nginx so that all communication is ssl. I want o know that

DO i need to upload ssl on nginx for `www.example.com or myserver.mydomain or its IP adddress`

Comment: It has to be domain name. www.example.com

Comment: Why did you add ansible related tags to your question?

Comment: You need to upload the SSL to the ELB if you are using the ELB that is more simple to do.

Comment: @error2007s i want to do ssl both from user to elb and then from elb to instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as per your comment if you want the SSL from the server side too. Then this are the two steps you need to follow.

1. Upload SSL for "www.example.com" on you server and configure nginex to server 443 port.
2. Change the ELB listeners from 443-80 to 443-443.

And it will work